# asp.net mvc application not working after publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, application-start

i have a wired problem with my app.
as along as i run my app using visual studio, there is no problem but when i try to publish and run it using IIS i get the following error

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Achasoft.AchaCms.Web.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) +813
   Achasoft.AchaCms.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +182

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9859725
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

i read some articles about Application_Start in IIS 7 but shouldnt the default (asp.net mvc application template) routing work...

Answer (score 1):

Please check the publish code that all the dll related to the MVC were published. Because by default MVC dll's was not copy to the local.

Comment: hi; i have made the references local copy; so all the dlls are available

Answer (score 0):

You should check these:

- Server features, that supports asp.net site.
- Too add all deployable dependencies.
- If you have database, to check connection string

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Hosting provider supports Specific version of MVC you are using or they even support MVC.

Comment: hi, mvc dlls are in bin directory too